# definition of chain homotopy

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

We can define the notion chain homotopy in the category of chain of $R-$modules. But do we have any definition of chain homotopy in any abelian category? 
Analogously I can define the notion of chain map in Abelian category (map between two chain making the ladder commute) but it seems if I define chain homotopy in the same manner as I do for chain of $R-$modules then it is difficult to check if two chain map are homotopic then they induce the same map in homology.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? We certainly don't want "any definition" of chain homotopy, but indeed we can "define chain homotopy in the same manner as I do for chain of $R$-modules." Are you really asking about the last part, how to check that chain homotopic maps induce the same map in homology? The first remark at the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes captures the essence of it.

Comment: Two chain maps $f,g$ of $R-$modules between $M_*, N_*$ are chain homotopic if there exists diagonal map $s_i:M_i\rightarrow N_{i+1}$, such that $f_i-g_i=n_{i+1}d_i+d_{i-1}m_i$ for all $i$. This is how we defined chain homotopy in the category of chain of $R-$modules. But in an arbitrary abelian category if we copy this definition then it might be tedious to prove that two chain homotopic maps induce the same map in homology because we are not allowed to touch elements. My question is : Is this definition correct at all? If so, how could one prove they induce the same map in homology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied in the question and noted in the comments, the module version of the definition of chain homotopy extends without change to any abelian category. To show that if $f$ and $g$ are chain homotopic, then they induce the same map on homology, we first have to define the induced map. Since homology is the quotient $\ker d / \textrm{im}~ d$, the map induced by $f$ is defined by restricting to $\ker d$ and the noting that modding out by $\textrm{im}~d$ results in a well-defined map. If $f-g = sd + ds$, then when restricting to $\ker d$ we get $f-g=ds$. This means that the image of $f-g$ is in $\textrm{im}~d$, and so is zero in homology.

Comment: Thanks. At first glance a bit worried because in arbitrary abelian category we are not allowed to verify on the level of representatives but after a bit thinking I agree with you.